# PHPMailer stops after 1st or 2nd e-mail in my for loop

Tags: php, xampp, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer 5.2 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable) in my localhost (XAMPP 3.2.2) and I have the following issue:

I want to send 1 e-mail to a lot of people (the message is slightly different for each one of them). So I created a `for` to go through all theses people's e-mails in an array, sending 1 e-mail to each of those addresses. The URL that I enter in my browser to run the `send-emails.php` is like `http://localhost/mailer/send-emails.php`, but soon after the 1st e-mail is sent, the webpage stops loading and nothing more happens (no log error, no exception, no console log, no nothing...). Sometimes, if I'm lucky, the localhost can send 2 e-mails from the array, but then it stops.

I don't know why the PHPMailer is stopping after the 1st or the 2nd e-mail are sent (in the example code bellow, it would only send to aaaa@gmail.com and, maybe, to bbb@gmail.com).

Can someone help?

The code is:

```
<?php
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', 3600);

include('PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'STARTTLS';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "xxxx@xxxx"; //my e-mail
$mail->Password = "xxx";       //my password
$mail->setFrom("xxxx@xxxx", "Xxxx");

//'To' addresses
$email = array("aaaa@gmail.com","bbb@gmail.com","cccc@gmail.com","dddd@gmail.com","eeee@gmail.com");

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($email); $i++) { 
    try {
        $mail->addAddress($email[$i]);
        //Blind copy to myself
        $mail->AddBCC("xxxx@xxxx", "Xxxx");

        $mail->Subject = "...";

        $mensagemHtml = "...";
        $mensagemBody = "...";
        $mail->msgHTML("<html>{$mensagemHtml}</html>");
        $mail->AltBody = "{$mensagemBody}";

        $mail->send();

        $mail->clearAddresses();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not your issue but I'd use a `foreach` rather than a `for`.

Comment: turn on debug mode in phpmailer. mailservers will have limits as to amount\size\ speed of sending, but your usage sounds to low for that to be the issue.

Comment: WHen I did it once back then, I used try before $mail = new PHPMailer(true); and foreach before try.

Comment: Also, check for mailer errors:if (!$mail->send()) {
        <do some error reporting>
        break;

Comment: Base your code on [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Comment: thanks for all the answers! I'll improve my code to follow all the recommendations